# Avoid color tween between default color and highlightColor for RawMaterialButton and FlatButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know whether there is a way to avoid the color tweening that happens upon clicking on a `RawMaterialButton` and `FlatButton`. There is a slight animation between the default color and the highlight color. I want this color switch to happen instantaneously.

Sample Button:

```
child: RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  highlightColor: Colors.red,
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
  fillColor: Colors.blue,
  elevation: 0.0,
  highlightElevation: 0.0,
  animationDuration: Duration.zero,
  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
),
```

Comment: Don't use a these button types if they don't do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own custom button using a `GestureDetector`. There is likely no way of getting what you want with these button types without modifying the source.

I created a sample button that instantly changes between the default and highlight color and takes an `onTap` parameter as well so it can be used very similarly to the button types you're used to.

```dart
class CustButton extends StatefulWidget {
  CustButton({this.onTap});
  
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  
  @override
  _CustButtonState createState() => _CustButtonState();
}

class _CustButtonState extends State<CustButton> {
  Color buttonColor = Colors.blue;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: buttonColor,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (details) {
          setState(() {
            buttonColor = Colors.red;
          });
          widget.onTap();
        },
        onTapUp: (details) {
          setState(() {
            buttonColor = Colors.blue;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```